# how to redirect non-www request to www?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, .htaccess

I have a Rails app and I have put this code in a .htaccess file in the public folder of the app:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example\.com)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but still the non-www is not redirecting to www and Chrome is saying: infinite loop. What am I doing wrong? I am using Apache with Passenger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove parenthesis and `?` from `RewriteCond`, to read like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd use the [rack-canonical-host](https://github.com/tylerhunt/rack-canonical-host) gem instead.

Add `gem 'rack-canonical-host'` to your `Gemfile`, run `bundle` and add this to your `config.ru`, just before the line starting with `run`:

```
use Rack::CanonicalHost, 'example.com'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try these rewrite condition and rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L]
```

Actually, the expression of your condition is such like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ [NC]
```